# Mostrar únicamente un valor de un array js

Tags: javascript

Verán tengo una variable llamada 'fetch' que guarda estos datos:

```
{
    "idusuario":"8",
    "idrol":"1",
    "nombre":"POLECAT",
    "tipo_documento":"DNI",
    "num_documento":"7777777777777777",
    "direccion":"CASA",
    "telefono":"8789499",
    "email":"correo@gmail.com",
    "cargo":"TESTER",
    "condicion":"1",
    "PRIMERA_VEZ":"NO",
    "fecha":"2021-06-11 00:51:06"
}
```

La cosa es que solo quiero mostrar en un mensaje de *JavaScript* el que dice PRIMERA_VEZ, no se como  e intentado de varias formas, tengo esto:

```
function(fetch)
{
    if (fetch!="null")
    {
        var info =[];
        info.push(fetch);
        var codigo = null;
        if (info.length) {
            codigo = info[0].PRIMERA_VEZ
        }
        bootbox.alert("mensaje con dato: "+codigo);
    }else{
        bootbox.alert("no hay mensaje");
    }
}
```

Me dice *undefined*. Si en el mensaje pongo 'fetch' en lugar de 'codigo', me salen todos los datos que menciono, pero solo quiero que muestre el dato especificado (primera_vez).

> **PD:** Al darle clic al botón, de un formulario se ejecuta la acción, nada mas.

Comment: Debes depurar tu variable `fetch`, de lo contrario nunca sabrás la razón del problema. Existen muchos métodos que aplicar para saber lo que contiene tu variable: `typeof`, `hasOwnProperty` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Según veo los datos de fetch son una cadena JSON, por lo tanto si utilizas `fetch.PRIMERA_VEZ` te retorna `undefined` ya que en la cadena no sabe como interpretar esa propiedad.

Me imagino que algo así es lo que pasa (daré nombre a la función y utilizaré un *alert* tradicional para mi ejemplo, todo lo demás de tu código lo dejo tal cual):

```js
fetch = `{
    "idusuario":"8",
    "idrol":"1",
    "nombre":"POLECAT",
    "tipo_documento":"DNI",
    "num_documento":"7777777777777777",
    "direccion":"CASA",
    "telefono":"8789499",
    "email":"correo@gmail.com",
    "cargo":"TESTER",
    "condicion":"1",
    "PRIMERA_VEZ":"NO",
    "fecha":"2021-06-11 00:51:06"
}`;
mostrar(fetch);

function mostrar(fetch)
{
    if (fetch!="null")
    {
        var info =[];
        info.push(fetch);
        var codigo = null;
        if (info.length) {
            codigo = info[0].PRIMERA_VEZ
        }
        alert("mensaje con dato: "+codigo);
    }else{
        alert("no hay mensaje");
    }
}
```

Bien hasta aquí el problema permanece mostrando:

> mensaje con dato: undefined

Ahora lo que debes hacer es utilizar `JSON.parse()` para poder convertir tu cadena a un objeto (Es lo único que modificarías en tu código).

De esta forma quedaría tu código:

```js
fetch = `{
    "idusuario":"8",
    "idrol":"1",
    "nombre":"POLECAT",
    "tipo_documento":"DNI",
    "num_documento":"7777777777777777",
    "direccion":"CASA",
    "telefono":"8789499",
    "email":"correo@gmail.com",
    "cargo":"TESTER",
    "condicion":"1",
    "PRIMERA_VEZ":"NO",
    "fecha":"2021-06-11 00:51:06"
}`;
mostrar(JSON.parse(fetch)); // Aquí parseamos tu cadena JSON

function mostrar(fetch)
{
    // También podrías parsear aquí según el caso
    if (fetch!="null")
    {
        var info =[];
        info.push(fetch);
        var codigo = null;
        if (info.length) {
            codigo = info[0].PRIMERA_VEZ
        }
        alert("mensaje con dato: "+codigo);
    }else{
        alert("no hay mensaje");
    }
}
```

De esta forma obtienes:

> mensaje con dato: NO

Puedes leer un poco más de `JSON.parse` [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: En realidad, podrías mejorar el código, ya que en su desespero por obtener la información mostró lo que tenía. Pero el arreglo está de mas. Simplemente con hacerle el JSON.parse y llamar a la key PRIMERA_VEZ vale para lo que la persona necesita.

Comment: @jorgeGomez, podrías tener razón en el sentido de que su código esté un tanto cambiado pero en mi experiencia respondiendo me di cuenta que es mejor dar un ejemplo funcional (ejecutable) cuando es posible hacerlo, entiendo que podría discrepar con la opinión de algunos de todas formas, tomaré en cuenta tu opinión para futuras respuestas. ;)

Comment: mucha gracias hermano, yo y mis practicas te lo agradecemos

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar ese tipo de datos ya sea un struct o un json. Tienes que buscar el elemento entre corchetes.

```
objeto
{
"vegetal":"no",
"molusco":"no",
"animal":"si"
}

objeto['molusco'];
```

Comment: El códigog es correcto. Si esa función recibe el argumento fetch debe funcionar, si no lo hace el error está fuera. No pones como creas el objeto fetch desde los datos del formulario.